# Boost.Asio Server and RAII

Tags: c++, networking, server, boost, raii

I am trying to implement a network server application in C++ using Boost.Asio.

Here are the requirements I am trying to meet:

- The Application creates only one instance of `boost::io_context`.
- Single `io_context` is being `run()` by a shared Thread Pool. The number of threads is not defined.
- Application can instantiate multiple Server objects. New Servers can be spawned and killed at any time.
- Each Server can handle connections from multiple clients.

I am trying to implement RAII pattern for the Server class. What I want to guarantee is that when Server gets deallocated all of its connections are completely closed. There are 3 ways each connection can be closed:

1. Client responds and there is no more work to be done in a connection.
2. Server is being deallocated and causes all alive connections to close.
3. Connection is killed manually by invoking `stop()` method.

I have arrived to a solution that seems to meet all of the criteria above but since Boost.Asio is still quite new to me I wanted to verify that what I am doing is correct. Also there are couple of things that I was specifically not 100% sure about:

- I was trying to remove the `mutex` from the Server class and instead use a `strand` for all of the synchronisation but I couldn't find a clear way to do it.
- Because Thread Pool can consist of only 1 thread and this thread may be what's calling a Server destructor I had to invoke `io_context::poll_one()` from the destructor to give a chance for all of the pending connections to complete the shutdown and prevent a potential deadlock.
- I would welcome any other suggestions for improvements you could think of.

Anyways, here's the code with some unit tests ( live version on Coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1afb0dc34dd09008 ):

```
#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_context_strand.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/executor.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/deadline_timer.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/dispatch.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace std::placeholders;


class Connection;


class ConnectionDelegate
{
public:
    virtual ~ConnectionDelegate() { }
    
    virtual class executor executor() const = 0;
    virtual void didReceiveResponse(shared_ptr<Connection> connection) = 0;
};


class Connection: public enable_shared_from_this<Connection>
{
public:
    Connection(string name, io_context& ioContext)
    : _name(name)
    , _ioContext(ioContext)
    , _timer(ioContext)
    {
    }
    
    const string& name() const
    {
        return _name;
    }
    void setDelegate(ConnectionDelegate *delegate)
    {
        _delegate = delegate;
    }
    
    void start()
    {
        // Simulate a network request
        _timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(3));
        _timer.async_wait(bind(&Connection::handleResponse, shared_from_this(), _1));
    }
    void stop()
    {
        _timer.cancel();
    }
    
private:
    string _name;
    io_context& _ioContext;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer _timer;
    ConnectionDelegate *_delegate;
    
    void handleResponse(const boost::system::error_code& errorCode)
    {
        if (errorCode == error::operation_aborted)
        {
            return;
        }
        dispatch(_delegate->executor(),
                 bind(&ConnectionDelegate::didReceiveResponse, _delegate, shared_from_this()));
    }
};


class Server: public ConnectionDelegate
{
public:
    Server(string name, io_context& ioContext)
    : _name(name)
    , _ioContext(ioContext)
    , _strand(_ioContext)
    {
    }
    ~Server()
    {
        stop();
        assert(_connections.empty());
        assert(_connectionIterators.empty());
    }
    weak_ptr<Connection> addConnection(string name)
    {
        auto connection = shared_ptr<Connection>(new Connection(name, _ioContext), bind(&Server::deleteConnection, this, _1));
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(_mutex);
            _connectionIterators[connection.get()] = _connections.insert(_connections.end(), connection);
        }
        connection->setDelegate(this);
        connection->start();
        return connection;
    }
    
    vector<shared_ptr<Connection>> connections()
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(_mutex);
        
        vector<shared_ptr<Connection>> connections;
        for (auto weakConnection: _connections)
        {
            if (auto connection = weakConnection.lock())
            {
                connections.push_back(connection);
            }
        }
        return connections;
    }
    void stop()
    {
        auto connectionsCount = 0;
        for (auto connection: connections())
        {
            ++connectionsCount;
            connection->stop();
        }
        
        while (connectionsCount != 0)
        {
            _ioContext.poll_one();
            connectionsCount = connections().size();
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - ConnectionDelegate
    class executor executor() const override
    {
        return _strand;
    }
    void didReceiveResponse(shared_ptr<Connection> connection) override
    {
        // Strand to protect shared resourcess to be accessed by this method.
        assert(_strand.running_in_this_thread());
        
        // Here I plan to execute some business logic and I need both Server & Connection to be alive.
        std::cout << "didReceiveResponse - server: " << _name << ", connection: " << connection->name() << endl;
    }
    
private:
    typedef list<weak_ptr<Connection>> ConnectionsList;
    typedef unordered_map<Connection*, ConnectionsList::iterator> ConnectionsIteratorMap;
    
    string _name;
    io_context& _ioContext;
    io_context::strand _strand;
    ConnectionsList _connections;
    ConnectionsIteratorMap _connectionIterators;
    mutex _mutex;
    
    void deleteConnection(Connection *connection)
    {
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(_mutex);
            auto iterator = _connectionIterators[connection];
            _connections.erase(iterator);
            _connectionIterators.erase(connection);
        }
        default_delete<Connection>()(connection);
    }
};


void testConnectionClosedByTheServer()
{
    io_context ioContext;
    auto server = make_unique<Server>("server1", ioContext);
    
    auto weakConnection = server->addConnection("connection1");
    assert(weakConnection.expired() == false);
    assert(server->connections().size() == 1);
    
    server.reset();
    assert(weakConnection.expired() == true);
}

void testConnectionClosedAfterResponse()
{
    io_context ioContext;
    auto server = make_unique<Server>("server1", ioContext);
    
    auto weakConnection = server->addConnection("connection1");
    assert(weakConnection.expired() == false);
    assert(server->connections().size() == 1);
    
    while (!weakConnection.expired())
    {
        ioContext.poll_one();
    }
    assert(server->connections().size() == 0);
}

void testConnectionClosedManually()
{
    io_context ioContext;
    auto server = make_unique<Server>("server1", ioContext);
    
    auto weakConnection = server->addConnection("connection1");
    assert(weakConnection.expired() == false);
    assert(server->connections().size() == 1);
    
    weakConnection.lock()->stop();
    ioContext.run();
    
    assert(weakConnection.expired() == true);
    assert(server->connections().size() == 0);
}

void testMultipleServers()
{
    io_context ioContext;
    auto server1 = make_unique<Server>("server1", ioContext);
    auto server2 = make_unique<Server>("server2", ioContext);

    auto weakConnection1 = server1->addConnection("connection1");
    auto weakConnection2 = server2->addConnection("connection2");

    server1.reset();
    assert(weakConnection1.expired() == true);
    assert(weakConnection2.expired() == false);
}

void testDeadLock()
{
    io_context ioContext;
    auto server = make_unique<Server>("server1", ioContext);
    
    auto weakConnection = server->addConnection("connection1");
    assert(weakConnection.expired() == false);
    assert(server->connections().size() == 1);
    
    auto connection = weakConnection.lock();
    server.reset(); // <-- deadlock, but that's OK, i will try to prevent it by other means
}


int main()
{
    testConnectionClosedByTheServer();
    testConnectionClosedAfterResponse();
    testConnectionClosedManually();
    // testDeadLock();
}
```

Kind Regards,
Marek

Answer (score 2):

I don't know enough Asio to give the kind of feedback I know you want, but here are some minor cleanups you could do:

- Don't `using namespace std`. You should probably avoid `using namespace` anything else, too, just for clarity.
- `virtual ~ConnectionDelegate() { }` could be `virtual ~ConnectionDelegate() = default;` instead. This represents your intent a little better.
- `~Server()` should be `~Server() override`, to indicate that it overrides a virtual member function. In general, you should use `override` wherever it's physically allowed by the language. (I think you do it right everywhere *except* on the destructors.)
- `Connection(string name,` and `Server(string name,` both unnecessarily makes a copy of `string name`.
- All your constructors should be `explicit`, to tell the compiler that e.g. the braced pair `{"hello world", myIOContext}` should not be implicitly treated as (or implicitly converted to) a `Server` object, not even by accident.
- Personally, I find the use of typedefs for `ConnectionsList` and `ConnectionsIteratorMap` to be an unnecessary layer of indirection. I would rather see `std::list<std::weak_ptr<Connection>> _connections;` right there in-line. If I need a name for that type, I can just say `decltype(_connections)`.
- `default_delete<Connection>()(connection)` is a verbose way of saying `delete connection`. Be direct.
- `class executor executor()` is hella confusing. The fact that you had to say `class` there should have been a red flag that either `executor` is not the right name for the class, or `executor()` is not the right name for this method. Consider changing the name of the method to `get_executor()`, for example. I assume that you can't change the name of `class executor` because it isn't declared in this file; it must be coming from some Boost namespace that you `using`'ed, right? (Don't `using` namespaces!)

---

You skip a lot of opportunities to avoid copies via references and/or move semantics. For example, in `Server::connections()`, I would have written:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Connection>> connections() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Connection>> result;
    for (const auto& weakConnection : _connections) {
        if (auto sptr = weakConnection.lock()) {
            result.push_back(std::move(sptr));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This avoids bumping the weak refcount by making `weakConnection` a reference instead of a copy, and then avoids bumping the strong refcount by using move instead of copy in `push_back`. Four atomic ops saved! (Not that this matters in real life, probably, but hey, welcome to Code Review.)

---

```
dispatch(_delegate->executor(),
         bind(&ConnectionDelegate::didReceiveResponse, _delegate, shared_from_this()));
```

I find the use of `bind` confusing, but I don't know for sure (and actually hope someone will comment and enlighten me) — is `bind` *needed* here? It would certainly be clearer-to-read, faster-to-compile, and no-slower-at-runtime to write

```
dispatch(
    _delegate->executor(),
    [self = shared_from_this(), d = _delegate]() {
        d->didReceiveResponse(self);
    }
);
```

This would make it a bit clearer what's actually being copied (one `shared_ptr` keeping `*this` alive, and one raw pointer). In fact, I wonder whether we even need to stash the copy of the raw pointer; could we get away with this instead?

```
dispatch(
    _delegate->executor(),
    [self = shared_from_this()]() {
        self->_delegate->didReceiveResponse(self);
    }
);
```

Or do you expect that sometimes you'll get into the body of that lambda with `d != self->_delegate` and that's why you need the extra pointer?

---

I also wonder whether it'd be possible to use `std::chrono::seconds` instead of `boost::posix_time::seconds`. Can Boost.Asio interoperate with C++11 `std::chrono` these days?

---

```
_connectionIterators[connection.get()] = _connections.insert(_connections.end(), connection);
```

I feel like the "cleverness" here is on the wrong side of the equals sign. `_connections.insert(_connections.end(), connection)` seems like a verbose way of writing `_connections.push_back(connection)`. Vice versa, I'm used to seeing people replace `map[k] = v` with `map.emplace(k, v)` for performance and clarity. Remember that `map[k] = v` first *default-constructs* `map[k]`, and then *assigns* a new value into it.

Ah, I see, you need to use `insert` because `insert` returns an iterator and `push_back` doesn't.

But that just raises the question: Why are you trying to shoehorn *two* side-effects into *one* line? If we're allowed two lines, we just do `push_back` and then set `map.emplace(connection.get(), std::prev(_connections.end()))`. Or, heck, at that point I wouldn't really complain about

```
auto it = _connections.insert(_connections.end(), connection);
_connectionIterators.emplace(connection.get(), it);
```

Having spotted the red flag, dig deeper: what's the *difference* between the one-liner and the clearer two-liner? Aha! The difference is what happens if `_connections.insert(...)` runs out of memory and throws. With the two-liner, `_connectionIterators` remains untouched. With the one-liner, you *first* default-construct some dangerous garbage in `_connectionIterators[connection.get()]` and *then* propagate the exception.

So I think there's a reasonable argument to be made in favor of the two-liner, just on general principles.

---

Again, this answer doesn't really address your main concern about RAII, but I hope it gives some food for thought anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. You're right that I am mostly interested in someone reviewing my Asio usage and handling of the lifetime of the connections. Nevertheless I still find your comments valuable, especially the points about explicit constructors, default destructors and executor() method. I will keep this question open in case some Asio expert will come across it.